# how to delete all elasticsearch data the fastest way

Tags: elasticsearch

My k8s elasticsearch cluster(v6.4.3) is resharding data for one day,now I do not want to wait.This is the cluster status:

```
# curl http://elasticsearch.logging:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
{
  "cluster_name" : "k8s-logs",
  "status" : "red",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 3,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 3,
  "active_primary_shards" : 2110,
  "active_shards" : 2110,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 12,
  "unassigned_shards" : 3000,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 31,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 18447190,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 41.194845763373685
}
```

Now I do not want to wait reshard any more,it is too slow,the data is test log and it is not important,so I want to delete all data. What is the fastest way to delete? I am tried this way:

```
curl -XDELETE http://elasticsearch.logging:9200/_all
```

It give a 503 error,could I directly delete the data folder using this command and restart cluster?

```
rm -rf es es1 es2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your elasticsearch container is running inside the Kubernetes cluster, you can simply delete the PVC created during the setup.

Just perform this command:

`kubectl delete pvc <elasticsearch-pvc-name>`

Comment: what is the recommended procedure before PVC deletion? I've tried to scale data and master pods to zero, but masters immediately start recreating, possibly because of configuration in `elasticsearches` resource. I do not want to remove this resource, because the goal is to wipe data and not the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to destroy/recreate ES cluster resource to wipe its data.

The issue that pods immediately start so I was not able to remove PVCs.

If I'm right, ES doesn't have pause option (please correct me in comments).

---

Make sure you really want to delete ES data and steps are:

```
kubectl -n namespace get pvc
kubectl -n namespace get my-elasticsearch-cluster elastic -o yaml > elasticsearch.backup

kubectl -n namespace delete elasticsearch my-elasticsearch-cluster
```

Deploy via Helm/Pipeline so resource should appear at `kubectl -n namespace get elasticsearch`

It should turn to healthy.

---

You could try to deploy with `kubectl apply -f elasticsearch.backup` instead, but you need to remove fields such as `resourceVersion`, etc.